# Chart.js drawing only in the top of canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I am using very slightly modified version of chart.js, my globals look like this

```
var barChartDemo = new Chart(ctx).Linechart(barChartData, {
  responsive: true,
  scaleShowHorizontalLines: false,
  scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
  tooltipYPadding : 8,
  animateScale : true,
  animationEasing : "easeOutBounce",
  pointDotRadius : 3,
  pointDotStrokeWidth: 3,
  tooltipCornerRadius : 0,
  tooltipFillColor : 'rgba(0,160,0,0.8)',
  scaleLineColor : 'transparent',
  scaleFontSize : 16,
  scaleFontColor : '#8ba2b0',
  scaleFontStyle : 'bold',
  showXAxisLabel:false,
  bezierCurve:false,
  datasetStrokeWidth:3
});
```

You can see the showXAxisLabel option which I added.

The source of chart.js was modified somewhere in the middle around line 1678 and it looks like this.

```
if(this.showXAxisLabel){ // just added this check
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(xPos, (isRotated) ? this.endPoint + 12 : this.endPoint + 8);
  ctx.rotate(toRadians(this.xLabelRotation) * -1);
  ctx.font = this.font;
  ctx.textAlign = (isRotated) ? "right" : "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = (isRotated) ? "middle" : "top";
  ctx.fillText(label, 0, 0);
  ctx.restore();
} // and this closing bracket
```

Everything is working fine. Almost always but for some reason the chart is always drawn on top of the canvas and it looks like this.

[image: Picture of wrongly drawn chart]

And to be honest with you all, I also have written an extension for the chart, which is just drawing the background and a line which is not visible in this chart.

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
  name: 'Linechart',
  initialize: function(data){
    Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.originalClear = this.clear;
    this.clear = function () {
      var datasets = this.datasets[0];
      var barHeight = 30;
      this.originalClear();
      var x = this.scale.calculateX(0)-5;
      var xmax = this.scale.calculateX(datasets.points.length)-x;

      this.chart.ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';

      var i = 0;
      var odd = false;

      while(i<180){
        if(!odd)                    
          this.chart.ctx.fillRect(x, i, xmax, barHeight);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#cacbcc";
        ctx.moveTo(x-3, i);
        ctx.lineTo(xmax+5, i);
        ctx.stroke();

        odd = !odd;
        i = i+barHeight;
      }

      i = x;
      while(i < ctx.canvas.width){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#cacbcc";
        ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(i, 180);
        ctx.stroke();
        i=i+50;
      }
    }
  },
  draw: function (ease) {
    var points = this.datasets[0].points;
    var y = this.scale.calculateY(goalLine);
    var x = this.scale.calculateX(points.length);
    var xmin = this.scale.calculateX(0)-5;
    Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this);
    drawLine(ctx,x,y,xmin);
    drawTextBG(ctx,goalLabel,font,x/3,y-12/2);
  }
});
```

The two helper functions drawLine and drawTextBG are defined as follows

```
function drawLine(ctx,x,y,xmin){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = orange;
  ctx.moveTo(xmin, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawTextBG(ctx, txt, font, x, y) {    
  ctx.save();
  ctx.font = font;
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
  ctx.fillStyle = orange;
  var width = ctx.measureText(txt).width;
  ctx.fillRect(x-width-10, y-1, width+20, parseInt(font, 10)+2);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.fillText(txt, x, y+1);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

Could you please tell me why the chart is drawn like this? And another question would be if it is possible to extend the chart area to fit the line if it's y value is higher than the maximum value of the datasets?

Thanks to everybody who even bothers with this.

Comment: You might want to set up a fiddle with your modified Chart.js, extension and data. Cheers!

Comment: Oh right, will do in few moments. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: So, I had to post another question. I'm closing this as I found out myself, that the problem is in the labels (even though, they are not shown) Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has no real solution. My problem was, I wanted to show the chart on 100% height of the canvas, which actually worked perfectly. The only thing my added check in the source of the chart.js was to not draw the labels on x-axis. But the calculations for them remained the same and changing the whole source would be painful and time consuming for me. So I left that idea behind and set all the labels as '' (empty) This is still no solution for me, but at least I found out how simple some solutions can be. It is not 100% resolved for me yet, but so that others know, I am looking for other answers.

[This is my new question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651162/hide-x-axis-labels-but-show-tooltips-in-chart-js)