# Hide x-axis labels but show tooltips in chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

I found many answers how to hide every nth label and yet still be able to show it in the tooltip. But there's a catch. If the label is very long, then the chart would be drawn somehow squished to the top of the canvas. It's logical. But is there any way to hide the labels, still show them in the tooltips and yet ignore them while calculating the y-values? So that the line can be drawn from top to bottom of the canvas?

Thank you for any advice!!

Comment: stripping of the label's, like making it empty strings before setting to the chart might help?

Comment: Sure, it indeed does. But then I don't know how to show them in the tooltips.

Comment: may be you can create a separate array with tooltip data. Or I remember formatting the tooltip. You can play around there

Comment: Would you help me point to the right tools I'd really be very thankful.

Comment: @jPO - check the 2nd part of the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32864384/360067

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the line chart to do this. Adapted from [Hide labels on x-axis ChartJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841302/hide-labels-on-x-axis-chartjs/32864384#32864384) (which was for bar charts) with some unneeded code removed.

What we do is pretty simple, we first set the labels array to blanks, allow the initialization to happen and finally loop through the points for the (first) dataset and set the labels to the original labels.

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
  name: "LineAlt",
  initialize: function(data){
    var originalLabels = data.labels;
    data.labels = data.labels.map(function() { return '' });

    Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.datasets[0].points.forEach(function(bar, i) {
      bar.label = originalLabels[i];
    });
  }
});
```

It's enough that you set the labels for the first dataset even if you have multiple datasets - when building a multiTooltip, the label is picked from the first dataset.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xjchy2dn/

Comment: Incredible! Thank you! And once again simple as that :)